# Cannot Find In Scope Despite Variable Declared In Class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pixel

I am programming a basic fps app on Xcode using Swift. The error comes in my Bitmap.swift file, which is meant to store pixels in a 2D array so that there's a way to represent an entire image in the app.

The code goes as follows:

```
import UIKit

class Bitmap: UIViewController {

    public struct Bitmap
    {
        public private(set) var pixels: [Color]
        public let width: Int
        
        public init(width: Int, pixels: [Color])
        {
            self.width = width
            self.pixels = pixels
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}


extension Bitmap
{
    var height: Int
    {
        return pixels.count / width
    }
    subscript(x: Int, y: Int) -> Color
    {
        get { return pixels[y * width + x] }
        set { pixels[y * width + x] = newValue}
    }
    convenience init(width: Int, height: Int, color: Color) {
        self.pixels = Array(repeating: color, count: width * height)
        self.width = width
    }
}
```

Despite having "pixels" and "width" declared in my class I keep getting these errors for my extension function:

"Cannot find 'pixels' in scope"
"Cannot find 'width' in scope"
"Value of type 'Bitmap' has no member 'pixels'"
"Value of type 'Bitmap' has no member 'width'"

Edit: Here is the code for my other file "Color.swift"

```
import UIKit

class Color: UIViewController {
    
    public struct Color {
        public var r, g, b, a: UInt8
        
        public init(r: UInt8, g: UInt8, b: UInt8, a: UInt8 = 255)
        {
            self.r = r
            self.g = g
            self.b = b
            self.a = a
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}


extension Color {
    static let clear = Color(r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0)
    static let black = Color(r: 0, g: 0, b: 0)
    static let white = Color(r: 255, g: 255, b: 255)
    static let gray = Color(r: 192, g: 192, b: 192)
    static let red = Color(r: 255, g: 0, b: 0)
    static let green = Color(r: 0, g: 255, b: 0)
    static let blue = Color(r: 0, g: 0, b: 255)
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have both a `class` *and* a `struct` named `Bitmap`. I'm guessing the `class` is erroneous, given your description of how you intend to use it.

Remove the `class` wrapped around the `struct` and remove `convenience`, which is not used for `struct`s:

```
public struct Bitmap
{
    public private(set) var pixels: [Color]
    public let width: Int
    
    public init(width: Int, pixels: [Color])
    {
        self.width = width
        self.pixels = pixels
    }
}


extension Bitmap
{
    var height: Int
    {
        return pixels.count / width
    }
    subscript(x: Int, y: Int) -> Color
    {
        get { return pixels[y * width + x] }
        set { pixels[y * width + x] = newValue}
    }
    init(width: Int, height: Int, color: Color) {
        self.pixels = Array(repeating: color, count: width * height)
        self.width = width
    }
}
```

Comment: Bitmap as a whole is meant to be a type that represents an entire image and the extension function is meant to be a computed property for the image height, as well as a convenience initializer for creating an empty image. Wouldn't removing the class render the rest of the code useless as it then won't be able to find Bitmap in scope?

Comment: @Hegazy1738 removing the class has nothing to do with whether `Bitmap` is in scope (in fact, almost the opposite since you were getting errors from shadowing the name before). Maybe you mean something else? Is there a reason that you think it should be a `UIViewController`? The code that I provided compiles fine and seems to fit your description in both your question *and* your comment. Did you try it out?

Comment: Yes I did, I'm still getting the same errors after copying and pasting your code. No matter where I put the public struct function ( since extension has to be outside the class can't be inside ) it keeps giving me the same errors.

Comment: The code I gave you compiles fine. Copy into a blank project and you'll be able to see that. It concerns me that you said "extension has to be outside the class" -- there is no more class in my example. Possible issues: 1) You need to clean and rebuild your project 2) You have other code (maybe another declaration of `Bitmap`?) in your project affecting this that isn't included in your question.

Comment: I removed the class from my code and I now get these errors at my public struct function
"Property cannot be declared public because its type uses an internal type"
"Initializer cannot be declared public because its parameter uses an internal type"

The errors I was getting in the extension function went away though

Comment: Have you declared Color somewhere? I assumed it was coming from SwiftUI. If not, it’ll need to be public. Or, the initial can’t be public.

Comment: Yes I have a file Color.swift which compiles fine.

Comment: I have added the code for my Color.swift file to the main question you can see it in the bottom of the question.

Comment: You have the same problem with Color. There’s basically never a situation I can think of where a struct should be wrapped by a class with the same name. Remove the surrounding class (same as I did with Bitmap)

Comment: Everything works now. Thanks a bunch! I really appreciate it.